# Getting error when trying to run application related to UserManager, IdentityRole etc

Tags: c#, asp.net, controller, usermanager

Getting error InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UserManager`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser]' while attempting to activate 'NostedServicePro.Controllers.BrukerController'.

BrukerController contructor (Bruker is the same as Account if that helps)

```
public class BrukerController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ServiceProDbContex _dbContext;
        private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger _logger;
        private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;
        private readonly IEmailSender _emailSender;


        public BrukerController(
                ServiceProDbContex dbContext,
                UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager,
                SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager,
                ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
                IEmailSender emailSender)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<BrukerController>();
            _userManager = userManager;
            _emailSender = emailSender;
        }
```

ConfigureServices method in startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ...

        // Configure the database context using the connection string from appsettings.json
        services.AddDbContext<ServiceProDbContex>(options =>
            options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"), ServerVersion.AutoDetect(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))));


        services.AddIdentity<NostedServicePro.Models.Bruker, IdentityRole>(options =>
        {
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
         })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ServiceProDbContex>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
        // ...
        services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = IdentityConstants.ApplicationScheme;
            options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
        }).AddIdentityCookies(options => { });

        services.AddAuthorization();


    }
```

Comment: You're registering Bruker as the identity user in Startup.cs yet you're passing in IdentityUser inside UserManager

Comment: @GHDevOps Should I change the NostedServicePro.Models.Bruker to something else in ConfigureServices? My UserEntity is named Bruker, does that change anything?
Changing the registering to Bruker gives me no problems, but should I also change it in the IdentityUser in the constructor?

Comment: If Bruker is inheriting from IdentityUser then yes, Bruker needs to be in the AddIdentity middleware. If you're not customizing anything in Identity, then IdentityUser needs to be in the middleware similar to how you're doing IdentityRole.